# Why "Timeout expired" exception thrown?

Tags: c#, .net

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

```
public class ModelDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ModelDBContext()
    {
    }

    public ModelDBContext(string strConnectionString)
        : base("SqlConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Region> Region { get; set; }
    public DbSet<State> State { get; set; }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Repository implementation class: Timeout error thrown from "ExecuteProcedure".

```
public class RepositoryBase<TResult, TModel> : IDisposable, IRepository<TResult, TModel>
    where TModel : class, new()
    where TResult : class, new()
{
    public RepositoryBase(ModelDBContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    protected ModelDBContext Context { get; set; }

    protected IEnumerable<TResult> ToList(IDbCommand command)
    {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var oColl = new List<TResult>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var item = new TResult();
                Map(reader, item);
                oColl.Add(item);
            }
            return oColl;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Map(IDataRecord record, TResult item)
    {
        // method to map reader properties to model 
    }

    public IEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteProcedure(TModel model, string storedProcedure)
    {
        var propertyInfos = typeof(TModel).GetProperties();

        using (var command = CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = storedProcedure;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            foreach (var property in propertyInfos)
            {                
                var value = property.GetValue(model, null);
                command.AddParameter(property.Name, value);
            }
            if (command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                command.Connection.Open();
            return ToList(command);
        }
    }

    public IDbCommand CreateCommand()
    {
        var cmd = Context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        return cmd;
    }

    #region dispose or cleanup

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~RepositoryBase()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.Context.Dispose();
        }
    }

    #endregion dispose or cleanup
}
```

The method "ExecuteProcedure" is called inside a loop (approx 1600 times).

Comment: Unfortunately we do not see where you manage the connection...

Comment: Connection management method available now

Comment: You still haven't posted the code that manages connections, there's two possible reasons why you get the error in the question. 1) you're trying to do too many things towards the database at the same time. This is unlikely, but still possible. 2) you're leaking connection objects, not disposing of them when you're done with them. This is much more likely.

Comment: I have updated the code section. In my case first reason " trying to do too many things towards the database at the same time" - repeatedly calling database inside loop.